# Google now card does not display

Tags: google-schemas

I've picked up examples from SO and using http://gmail-actions.appspot.com/ to send emails containing this exact schema. No cards are showing up on my mobile phone. Any clues?

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "EventReservation",
  "reservationNumber": "E123456789",
  "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
  "underName": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "Test Person"
  },
  "reservationFor": {
    "@type": "Event",
    "name": "Test Event",
    "startDate": "2015-06-25T02:00:00+05:30",
    "location": {
      "@type": "Place",
      "name": "Your Home",
      "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress": "111 Main Street",
        "addressLocality": "Columbus",
        "addressRegion": "OH",
        "postalCode": "43215",
        "addressCountry": "US"
      }
    }
  },
  "modifyReservationUrl": "http://www.test.com/testing"
}
</script>
<div>Test Appointment</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If it helps, I was attempting email delivery at 2015-06-25T00:32:00+05:30 which is 1.5 hours before the startDate. My location is not the same as that in the card. May be that's a reason?

Answer (score 0):

Your markup looks good and didn't find any errors using the [Email Markup Tester](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester). Based off your time zone (+05:30), I'm assuming you're not local to Columbus, Ohio. Try inputting an address local to you to trigger a Now card.

Also, you can find more EventReservation examples at the following:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/event-reservation

It would definitely be worth trying the [Music Event with ticket](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/event-reservation#sports_or_music_event_with_ticket) example, since it utilizes more attributes.

Let me know you're results after changing your address attributes.

Comment: @NishantS could you try inputting a valid address.

Comment: Nope, no dice. This is frustrating. How does one go about debugging these issues? The validator says the schema is ok. I see that the email was delivered. The gmail app on the device synced it. I see the 'Modify reservation' button on the browser as well. Wtf!

Comment: @NishantS relax, I got your back. Try inputting a earlier startDate, like 15-20 minutes away.

Comment: @NishantS here is my result (http://goo.gl/TlnBY6) using your script (http://pastebin.com/E9TkW3s7) and made sure to send it from http://gmail-actions.appspot.com. The attributes I did change were the name, which I changed to "Nishant." I used the venue (AT&T Park) from the documentation (https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/event-reservation). Try inputting a popular venue/address and inputting an earlier startDate and not 1.5 hours away.